# Android. Gradle build error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, gradle

How set "<" and ">" as text in my button?

My xml:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=">"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
```

Gradle build error:
Error:(59) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: Try `android:text="\>"`.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier I try this and clear & rebuild project, but problem still occurs :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file is [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), you need to correctly [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) the greater-than character in your attribute value:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="&gt;"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Certain charactes in XML cannot be used directly. This includes i.e. `&`, `<` and `>` which must be replaced by [corresponding entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping). So instead of

```
android:text=">"
```

you must write:

```
android:text="&gt;"
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `>` directly use `&gt;` code.
refere [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) doc
use [this](http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html) to generate codes